# CakePHP 2.x - Using Plugins with a Shell Command

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, plugins

I am currently trying to use the following Stripe plugin for CakePHP 2.x:

https://github.com/chronon/CakePHP-StripeComponent-Plugin

I have created a Shell Command that tries to utilise one of the functions of the Stripe Library.

my bootstrap is as below:

```
App::import('Vendor', array('file' => 'autoload'));
CakePlugin::load('Stripe');
```

and I have defined the following at the header of the Shell Command:

```
App::uses('Shell', 'Console');
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('StripeComponent', 'Stripe.Controller/Component');
```

Finally, in the main function, I have written the following:

```
$collection = new ComponentCollection();
$StripeComponent = new StripeComponent($collection);
$controller = new Controller();
$StripeComponent->initialize($controller);
$sub = $StripeComponent->stripeFunction($data);
```

When I am executing the command, the following error appears:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Stripe' not found in /var/www/html/myapp/app/Plugin/Stripe/Controller/Component/StripeComponent.php on line 367
Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in /var/www/html/myapp/app/Plugin/Stripe/Controller/Component/StripeComponent.php on line 367
Fatal Error Error: Class 'Stripe' not found in [/var/www/html/myapp/app/Plugin/Stripe/Controller/Component/StripeComponent.php, line 367]

The error appears to be causing problems on this line in StripeComponent, which appears to indicate that the plugin is not loaded during the execution of the command:

```
Stripe::setApiKey($this->key);
```

It seems to appear that the plugin was not correctly loaded when executing the Command (The Plugin works for the rest of the App).  Is there something that I am doing incorrectly that affects the loading of the plugin?  Or can't shell commands load all of the plugins prior to execution?

Any direction is most appreciated.

Comment: just to be clear, did you install  [Stripe's PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)?

Comment: Its said in the documentation, you need to install Stripe PHP library.. **You will need the component (packaged as a plugin), and Stripe's PHP library.**

Comment: Thanks Shahonseven, the documentation does say that.  I'll investigate when in front of machine next and update if required.

Comment: you're welcome...

Comment: @shahonseven The Stripe PHP Library is included as part of the plugin, and the Stripe PHP Library code is contained in myapp/app/Plugin/Stripe/Vendor/Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to call a startup method as opposed to initialize:

```
$collection = new ComponentCollection();
$StripeComponent = new StripeComponent($collection);
$controller = new Controller();
//$StripeComponent->initialize($controller);
$StripeComponent->startup($controller);
$sub = $StripeComponent->stripeFunction($data);
```

To answer the initial question, Shell Commands do indeed allow access to the Plugin library code.

Comment: That should be refactored, a component is definitely the wrong place for that code.